# Avoiding race condition in enum-based Finite State Machine

Tags: java, android, state-machine

I have an `enum`-based state machine. The following is example code to illustrate the structure of my states and the issue I have.

```
public enum LinkStates implements StuffDoneListener {

    ...

    DO_SOME_WORK {
        public void process() {
            ....
            ....
            someObject.startDoingSpecialStuff();
            outerClass.toState(WAIT_FOR_EVENT);
        }
    },


    WAIT_FOR_EVENT {
        public void process() {
            // does nothing
        }

        public void onSpecialStuffComplete() {

        }
    }

    ...

    // Default implementation of interface methods which individual states
    // may override at will
    public void onSpecialStuffComplete() {
    }

}
```

The `process()` method is what is called when the state is changed. Each state also tends to override various listener methods to receive various events.

State `DO_SOME_WORK` calls a method (`startDoingSpecialStuff()`) on an object to cause it to do some lengthy work. That object does its work on another non-UI `Thread`. When it is done, the state machine is notified via `onSpecialStuffComplete()`, which is called on the original thread that invoked the work. The obvious problem here is that if the work is done quickly, there could be a race condition in that the FSM moves into `WAIT_FOR_EVENT` after the listener callback has fired.

It is quite trivial for me to 'fix' this, perhaps by also overriding the `onSpecialStuffComplete()` in `DO_SOME_WORK`, so that if it gets notified within there it knows not to bother going to `WAIT_FOR_EVENT`. Or I could use a somewhat crude `boolean` flag that `WAIT_FOR_EVENT` polls as soon as it moves into that state to check if the event already fired.

What I am looking for however is a more elegant, robust solution to this general problem.

I have used the `Android` tag even though this could be considered a general Java design pattern question, just in case there's a better solution I could use that relies on Android-specific classes.

Comment: Is DO_SOME_WORK.process called on your "UI" thread (the same one that "onSpecialStuffComplete" is called on)?  If so, I don't see a race condition.  If not - is there a reason you can't have DO_SOME_WORK.process reverse the order of its calls, so that outerClass is in WAIT_FOR_EVENT before specialStuff is even started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `DO_SOME_WORK` and `WAIT_FOR_EVENT` can be merged. A state transition does not have to occur until "special stuff" is finished:

```
public enum LinkStates implements StuffDoneListener {
    // ...

    START_SOME_WORK_AND_WAIT {
        public void process() {
            // ....
            someObject.startDoingSpecialStuff();
        }

        public void onSpecialStuffComplete() {
            outerClass.toState(EVENT_IS_COMPLETE);
        }
    },

    EVENT_IS_COMPLETE {
        public void process() {
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    }

    // ...

    public void onSpecialStuffComplete() {
    }
}
```

I don't see a race condition when it is written this way, so assuming it does not break something that was not posted, it should work well.

Comment: Many thanks. Though the real code is far more complex, you got me thinking and conceptually I have something fairly similar to this now. The main point learned here is to be careful about choice of states and eliminate the race condition in the first place by triggering events and receiving the subsequent callbacks within the one state.